# write file by mmap, but when I use fread, the second time read error data

Tags: c, linux, mmap, fread

When I use mmap and memcpy to write a file, and then I use fread to read the data.
Below is my code, The problem is the first time i can read the **a**, but the second time i can't read a. 
I guess there is something like seek position in fread function, when I use memcpy to write file, It may change the seek position.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{


    int fd = open("./aa", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    FILE* f = fopen("./aa", "r");
    if (ftruncate(fd, 1024) < 0) {
        printf("ftruncate error\n");
    }
    void* base;
    if ((base = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("mmap error\n");
    }
    char* file_ptr = (char *)base;
    char buffer[256];
    char scratch[256];
    buffer[0] = 'a';
    memcpy(file_ptr, buffer, 1);
    file_ptr += 1;
    size_t n = fread(scratch, 1, 1, f);
    printf("size n %zu\n", n); // this output size n 1
    printf("scratch %c\n", scratch[0]); // this output scratch a
    memcpy(file_ptr, buffer, 1);
    file_ptr += 1;
    n = fread(scratch, 1, 1, f);
    printf("size n %zu\n", n); // this output size n 1
    printf("scratch %c\n", scratch[0]); // but this output scratch  
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :
size n 1
scratch a
size n 1
scratch

Comment: Note: this probably wont affect the result, but if you are intend to code in C you should not be using `#include <iostream>` . (or `#include <pthread>` if your program is not using posix threads)

Comment: fread() is buffered I/O. Run your program under strace to see what it does.

Comment: This program also segfaults if the file `aa` doesn't exist yet when you run it - you need to test the value of `f` is not `NULL`

Comment: @6EQUJ5 Thanks, I have change my code

Comment: fread() rreads x characters, leaving the file descriptor 'f' pointing x characters into the file.  The next fread() begins where the last fread stopped, unless fseek() is used between the two fread()s to change the file descriptor 'f' back at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, @wildplasser is right, your program may work, but if you go on mixing mmap and stdio you'll need to make sure that writes done via `mmap` get committed (use the `msync()` function) and that fread isn't buffering stale data (`fseek()`ing to the current position should do the trick).

Coming to your question: your program doesn't print "scratch", it prints "scratch \0" :)

Seriously, what you do is initialize the **size** of the "aa" file via `ftruncate()`, which is the same as filling the missing bytes up to 1024 '\0'; you write an 'a', and read it; then you read another character, and you get one of the NULs.

Try printing the ascii character of scratch[0] and you'll see it's zero; if you're still not convinced, try adding something like

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    file_ptr[i] = "QWERTY"[i];
```

right before the first memcpy and see what happens.

Comment: I saw it print scratch W. @wildplasser is Right, fread have a buffer, the second time I call fread, It will read data from it's buffer, not directly from the file.. So when I change the file, the second time fread have no sense.